# Why do Ignored Tags just highlight out, rather than disappearing like on SO?

Tags: support, tags

Obviously there are some questions I can't answer, nor am I that interested in them (e.g. `facebook`). I tried adding them to the ignored tags list, but they just show up slightly grey. I was expecting it to be StackOverflow like, and I would not see them at all.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in [your preferences](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1156/the-communist-duck?tab=prefs) called "Hide Ignored Tags". You need this marked in order for the tags to be hidden, rather than just greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

SO has some more rigorous filtering of the front page so that it doesn't show ignored tags and prefers interesting tags.  The idea being that they want to present a list of questions that are more interesting to the user.  That, and just showing "latest" like the other SE sites would be a lot of noise due to the sheer amount of traffic they get.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

So the reason you're seeing them here and not there is due to the filtering, unless you turned on that "hide ignored tags" flag that was brought up already.